# Specify the location of the tooltip when hovering over an element

Tags: html, css

When I mouse over `div.divClass`, the tooltip text should show.

How can I achieve that?

```css
.divClass {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<div class="divClass">
  <a href="#" title="Tooltip text"> test </a>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**

*Actually I want to show tooltip top of the ANCHOR element when mouse over on div. If I add title in Div means I'm getting alignment issue.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `title` attribute cannot force a tooltip to appear in one fixed location, regardless of where the hover occurs. That's not normally how the tooltip works. However, here's a method that may work for you.

```css
.divClass {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span { display: none; }

.divClass:hover > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="divClass">
  <a href="#"  title="Tooltip text"> test </a>
  <span>Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cc3pm8zy/)

References:

- [`title` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) ~ MDN
- [Global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) ~ MDN